# How do I write a query to pull data from a table where linked table value is NULL or not exists

Tags: sql

I need to write a query to pull claims from members that do not appear in the `double_coverage` table.

In one table I have claims data - CLAIMS Table
In the second table I have member details with other coverage called `double_coverage` table.

I want to pull all claims except for members that appear on the second table.

The final result should only for subscriber id

```
 1000007, 1000008   & 1000009
```

I have tried NOT IN but it's not working. Please help.

The SQL I am trying is:

```
 SELECT A.claim_id,
       A.subscriber_id,
       A.first_service_date dos,
       A.Payer_ID,
       DC.INSURANCE_ID,
       DC.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
       DC.STATUS,
  FROM CLAIMS A,
   (SELECT SUBSCRIBER_ID,
               EFFECTIVE_DATE,
               INSURANCE_ID, PAYER_ID
               FROM double_coverage ) DC
WHERE  DC.SUBSCRIBER_ID = A.SUBSCRIBER_ID
       AND DC.PAYER_ID = A.PAYER_ID
       AND A.SUBSCRIBER_ID NOT IN (select SUBSCRIBER_ID from double_coverage)
```

[DOUBLE_COVERAGE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWvi4.png)[CLAIMS TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpr80.png)

Comment: Start using explicit `INNER JOIN` syntax to join two tables instead of Old style comma separated join

Comment: You seem to be explicitly `JOIN`ing the `Double_Coverage` table by `subscriber_id`, but then have the `WHERE` condition of the `subscriber_id` not being in the `Double_Coverage` table, so of course it's not going to return any rows. It can't both be there and not be there.

Answer (score 1):

`left join` on the claims table and see which id's don't exist with a `where` condition.

```
select c.claim_id,
       c.subscriber_id,
       c.first_service_date dos,
       c.Payer_ID
from claims c
left join double_coverage dc on dc.subscriber_id = c.subscriber_id
where dc.subscriber_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want things that don't exist, just use `not in` or `not exists`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CLAIMS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM double_coverage dc
                  WHERE dc.subscriber_id = c.subscriber_id AND
                        dc.PAYER_ID = c.PAYER_ID
                 );
```